# Depth test works when translating, but not when specifying z-coordinates (2D rendering)

Tags: android, opengl-es, depth-buffer, opengl-es-3.0

### Problem

It seems that I've found an issue with depth testing in Android OpenGL ES 3.0.
Either that, or I somehow have an implementation flaw.  I notice that depth testing works fine when I translate my geometry via modifying the model matrix; however, when I try to do the same through specifying position data in my geometry, the depth test fails.  Geometry which is rendered last appears behind previously rendererd geometry.

---

My objective is to perform 2D rendering such that each pixel corresponds to 1 unit in world space.  To do this, I have the following calls to `glViewport` and `Matrix.orthoM` to setup the projection matrix:

```
GLES30.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
Matrix.orthoM(projectionMatrix, 0, 0, width, 0, height, 0, 10.0f);
```

This should cause the projection to use the full width and height of  a `TextureView` and give a clip-space of 10 units in depth (z-axis).

During surface creation I make sure to enable depth testing (which uses the default depth function):

```
GLES30.glEnable(GLES30.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Last but not least, I also ensure to clear the depth buffer each draw frame:

```
GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES30.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The above calls should setup depth buffering.  All that remains is to define a view matrix which is done below during the each draw frame before rendering any geometry:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

The parameters specify `eyePosition = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}` which is away from the screen (toward the viewer), and the eye is looking at `centerPosition = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}`, which is the origin of the world.  This view matrix should only move the camera away from the scene without rotating (since I am rendering in 2D).

---

### Translating geometry with model matrix:

By translating geometry with the model matrix, I can effectively get the depth test to work properly.  Geometry renders in order according to a specified z-index.

Inside the draw function the following code executes for each rectangle (piano key) that I wish to draw:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
if (keys[index].keyType == WHITE_KEY) {
    Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, keys[index].zIndex);
} else {
    Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, keys[index].zIndex);
}
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, translateX, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model"), 1, false, modelMatrix, 0);
GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view"), 1, false, viewMatrix, 0);
GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, false, projectionMatrix, 0);

keys[index].draw();
```

This gives the proper result.  Notice all black keys appear on top even though all keys are rendered in order from left to right.

[image: Depth Test Working]

### Translating geometry with position data:

I wished to specify z-index in the actual vertex data of the rectangles.  So instead of the above render code, I use the following:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, translateX, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model"), 1, false, modelMatrix, 0);
GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view"), 1, false, viewMatrix, 0);
GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, false, projectionMatrix, 0);

keys[index].draw();
```

Notice that the only difference is that I am no longer translating the geometry according to the z-index value.  Instead, I specify the z-index in the actual vertex data:

```
float[] vertexData = new float[] {
        x, y, zIndex, //Specify z-index in vertex data.
        0, 0, //Texture coordinates.
        x + width, y, zIndex, //Specify z-index in vertex data.
        1, 0, //Texture coordinates.
        x, y + height, zIndex, //Specify z-index in vertex data.
        0, 1, //Texture coordinates.
        x + width, y + height, zIndex, //Specify z-index in vertex data.
        1, 1  //Texture coordinates.
};

int[] indexData = new int[] {
        0, 1, 3,
        0, 3, 2
};

//Set up VAO, VBO, and EBO with the data above (works properly, but is
//provided for the sake of completion).
FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexData.length * 4)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
vertexBuffer.put(vertexData).position(0);

IntBuffer indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indexData.length * 4)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
indexBuffer.put(indexData).position(0);

GLES30.glGenVertexArrays(1, vao, 0);
GLES30.glGenBuffers(1, vbo, 0);
GLES30.glGenBuffers(1, ebo, 0);

GLES30.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);

GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData.length * 4, vertexBuffer, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo[0]);
GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexData.length * 4, indexBuffer, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Point to vertex positions (stride = size of vertex in bytes = 5 components *4 bytes per float = 20)
GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, 0);

GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, VERTEX_POSITION_COMPONENTS * 4);

GLES30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

When the translations are removed, I receive the following results.  Notice that the last keys are rendered behind the previous keys despite the fact we are rendering them from left to right.  Also note that `zIndex = -1.0f` for white keys while `zIndex = 0.0f` for black keys.  This should cause the white keys to be further into the screen compared to black keys.  Both keys should be visible inside the clipping-space provided to `Matrix.orthoM` (since the view matrix was translated away from the screen by 1 unit, the effective *zNear* and *zFar* values are `1.0f` and `-9.0f` respectively).

[image: Depth Test Not Working]

---

### Question

What do I need to do in order to specify `zIndex` in the vertex data while having the correct depth test results?

---

### Code

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 300 es

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);

    //Pass texture coordinate to fragment shader.
    TexCoord = texCoord;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 300 es

in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    vec2 flippedTexCoord = vec2(TexCoord.x, 1.0 - TexCoord.y);
    color = texture(texture, flippedTexCoord);
}
```

Comment: did you try feeding '-1.0' for black keys and 0.0 for white keys, in your vertex data

Comment: You bet! But it doesn't resolve it.  Though it'd make sense if for some reason the camera is backwards...

Comment: Also, am wondering how you have 5 components in vertexdata array for each vertex. x, y, z, 0, 1

Comment: Each vertex is composed of 3 position components and 2 texture coordinate components (notice that strides are used for vertex attribute pointers).  I was trying to refrain from posting all code for simplicity sake.  Edited with more comments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting up your position attribute to have only 2 components:

```
GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, 0);
```

The second argument specifies the number of components. So this should be:

```
GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, 0);
```

Or, since you seem to have a constant defined for this purpose, you might as well use it here:

```
GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, VERTEX_POSITION_COMPONENTS, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, VERTEX_STRIDE, 0);
```

Comment: Indeed this was the case.  I sure was bold to say that section worked properly, so I'm glad you didn't trust me!

Apologies for this being too localized, hopefully it helps someone else down the road.